# anyone knows what programming language or what technology uses Toby (chrome extension)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

[This is the extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toby-for-chrome/hddnkoipeenegfoeaoibdmnaalmgkpip?hl=en) and I was wondering what programming language used the creator or creators because it works really well. I'd appreciate the answers if anyone knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome extensions are written with javascript, html, and css. [Source](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)

Comment: all of them? could you use some bindings? Like [this](http://code.google.com/p/cefpython/) found [here](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-make-a-Google-Chrome-extension-using-Python)

Comment: @Mrquestion That is using javascript to make calls to a webpage that is running python on the server. So yes in that way you can use other languages to program extensions, but the main application I believe can only be javascript because extensions are basically webpages.

Comment: Actually, if it uses databases can't be only Javascript so really appreciate your explanation but I'm asking about specifically that extension and not in general.

Comment: FYI you can actually look at the source code for the extension if you want. You may be able to find references to what external dependencies it uses, although it is minified script so it can be hard to read. You can find the source code in the chrome path something like `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\Extensions`

Comment: Windows? I have Mac

Comment: @Mrquestion you can use JS to make API calls which then store data to db on remote servers